# How to implement an array to store dice/remove them based of rolls?

Tags: java, arrays, random, dice

I was given a homework problem that I mostly understand. However, I need to have an array for my 5 dice. I didn't know how to go about setting up the array were I could roll the dice and if they land on a 2 or 5 they get removed from the dice. At the moment the only thing that makes my while loop work is my scoring system. Which I need have the array in there instead saying while I have dice/die keep rolling. Anyway, I think I have done most of the work except for the array that stores the dice. I am pretty new to programming and would like to understand this for the future.

Here is a brief summary of what I need my program to do:

1. Make an array of five dice
2. Roll a the 5 dice. (6 sided).
3. a. Check for the presence of a 2.
   b. Check for the presence of a 2 or 5.
4. If there is a 2 or 5, the sum is 0, and the number of dice available is reduced by the number of 2s or 5s.
5. If there is no 2 or 5, sum the dice and add it to the total.
6. While there are dice to roll, keep going until you run out of dice.

I've already written the code most of way that fulfils the requirements of the game. However, I am stuck on the array and can't figure out how to implement it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StuckInTheMudd {

    static int rollDice() {

        int die1 = (int) (6 * Math.random()) + 1;
        return die1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int die1;
        int die2;
        int die3;
        int die4;
        int die5;

        int playerPoints = 0;
        int roundPoints = 0;
        String answer;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello, Welcome To Stuck In The Mud");

        while (playerPoints <= 100) {
            System.out.println("Please roll the dice by pressing 'y' and hitting enter");
            System.out.println("o=================o");

            answer = input.next();

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                die1 = rollDice();
                die2 = rollDice();
                die3 = rollDice();
                die4 = rollDice();
                die5 = rollDice();

                System.out.println("Dice 1: " + die1);
                System.out.println("Dice 2: " + die2);
                System.out.println("Dice 3: " + die3);
                System.out.println("Dice 4: " + die4);
                System.out.println("Dice 5: " + die5);

                if (die1 == 2 || die2 == 2 || die3 == 2 || die4 == 2 || die5 == 2) {
                    roundPoints = 0;
                    System.out.println("The Player loses the points for this round.");
                    System.out.println("o=================o");
                    System.out.println("Players points: " + playerPoints);
                    System.out.println("o=================o");
                } else if (die1 == 5 || die2 == 5 || die3 == 5 || die4 == 5 || die5 == 5) {
                    roundPoints = 0;
                    System.out.println("The Player loses the points for this round.");
                    System.out.println("o=================o");
                    System.out.println("Players points: " + playerPoints);
                    System.out.println("o=================o");
                } else {
                    roundPoints = roundPoints + die1 + die2 + die3 + die4 + die5;
                    playerPoints = playerPoints + roundPoints;
                    System.out.println("Current Round Points: " + roundPoints);
                    System.out.println("o=================o");}

            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again.");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Game Over and end of loop");
    }
}
```

Once again I need to have an array that stores my dice. If the dice land on 2s or 5s they are removed from the array. This cycle will continue until I have no more dice left and the game ends.

Comment: What about a `List<Integer>` that stores the dices (here just: `int`s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an int array for the dice items but I would not remove items from it (if you want to do this then a `List` is a much better option)

```
int[] dices = new int[5];
```

I would use a simple constant value to mark a specific dice as removed, -1 is good for this.

```
private final static int NO_DICE = -1;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] dices = new int[5];

    int playerPoints = 0;
    int roundPoints = 0;
    String answer;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome To Stuck In The Mud");

    while (playerPoints <= 100) {
        System.out.println("Please roll the dice by pressing 'y' and hitting enter");
        System.out.println("o=================o");

        answer = input.next();

        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dices.length; i++) {
                if (dices[i] == NO_DICE) {
                    continue;
                }
                dices[i] = rollDice();
                System.out.println("Dice " + i + ": " + dices[i]);
            }
```

and then when checking for 2 or 5

```
for (int i = 0; i < dices.length; i++) {
    if (dices[i] == NO_DICE) {
        continue;
    }
    if (dices[i] == 2 || dices[i] == 5) {
         dices[i] = NO_DICE;
         roundPoints = 0;
         //...
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also, how would one go about doing this with a list? Also, loved how you formatted out your response it was very easy for me to understand!

Comment: @WillTAuten If you use an ArrayList for instance much of the code will be the same but you could skip the check with `NO_DICE` and instead call `remove` for 2 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make use of a bitmask instead of an array:

```
int bitmask = 0b11111; // 5 bits = 5 dice
```

To read how many dices there are just use `Integer.bitCount()`:

```
int dicesLeft = Integer.bitCount(bitmask);
```

To remove a die you can use bit shifting:

```
bitmask >>= n;
```

Where `n` is the amout of dices you want to remove

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't remove from an array per se as the size is fixed upon creation (so if you could use a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of some sort - that would make it much easier). Therefore, you're going to have to create a new array without the element(s) you don't want.

Perhaps loop through the existing array, and set the values in the new array for each one, except if it's a two or a five. Here's a simple example:

```
static int[] removeElementFromArray(int[] arr) {
    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length - 1];
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != 5 && arr[i] != 2) {
            newArr[temp] = arr[i];
            temp++;
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Here's an **[online](https://ideone.com/7raQuc)** example, but obviously store the returned array instead of printing it

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also how would I go about using a list? If you wouldn't mind showing me I would much appreciate it.